# Heavens gate code

Tags: windbg, x64dbg, pintool, api-reversing

Recommend me please how and what better to reverse the code containing `"heavens gate"`? What tool to bypass protection? Thank you.

```
I use Intel Pin

    push cs
    push 0xa02829
    jmp far 0xac9ba1, 0x33
```

Comment: Please translate the title to English too. What specific problems are you having that traditional tools do not work? Add more details and maybe some example snippets of whatever you have.

Comment: Still unclear what is the actual problem you’re having and what doesn’t work.

Comment: the problem is that the program code contains transitions between 32 and 64 bit modes ... and I ask for recommendations on how to reverse such a code, since standard tools are simply powerless